# Why is this combination of HTML and CSS to set font color and style failing?

Tags: html, css, meteor, fonts, colors

I am trying to put some red, italicized text (label) on a page:

### HTML

```
<label class="reditalic">Enter numeric values only</label>
```

### CSS

```
.reditalic {
  color: "red";
  font-style: "italic";
}
```

...but it fails, with:

"*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token YInfoReceiver.doXhr.xo.onfinish @ sockjs-0.3.4.js:2018EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs-0.3.4.js:151AbstractXHRObject._start.that.xhr.onread*"

and, "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Y*"

in the Browser (Chrome) Console, and "Your application has errors. Waiting for file change." in the console when running "meteor" in the directory of the app.

I also tried this (no quotes around "italic"):

```
.reditalic {
  color: "red";
  font-style: italic;
}
```

...and this ("oblique" instead of "italic"):

```
.reditalic {
  color: "red";
  font-style: oblique;
}
```

...and this ("font-color" instead of "font"):

```
.reditalic {
  font-color: "red";
  font-style: italic;
}
```

...and this (no quotes around "red"):

```
.reditalic {
  font-color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

It runs fine when I remove the HTML and the CSS shown above.

### UPDATE

The problem was that the HTML was in "limbo":

```
</table>    
</body>
<label class="reditalic">Enter numeric values only</label>
```

I changed it to this:

```
</table>
<label class="reditalic">Enter numeric values only</label>
</body>
```

...and the errors disappeared. It's still not displaying on the page, though, for some reason, even after saving the changes in the HTML file and refreshing the page.

Whether I use this:

```
color: red;
```

...or this:

```
color: "red";
```

...in the CSS, it makes no difference - the label does not display. For "full disclosure" here is the pertinent CSS:

```
.reditalic {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

..and HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Duckbilled Platypi R People 2!</title>
</head>
<body>
. . .
<label class="reditalic">Enter numeric values only</label>
</body>
```

What may or may not be a problem is that when I modify and save the HTML or CSS, I see this in the console:

```
Client modified -- refreshing
```

...but it never gets to the:

```
App running at: http://locohost:3000/
Type Control-C twice to stop.
```

...message...and yet it is really refreshing - I made a test change to the title, and it did change, so...???

Comment: can you please show us how you've linked/included your css file?

Comment: I would bet my left arm non of these errors have anything to do with the html & css you posted

Comment: @Amit: Then why does it run fine when they are removed? Save your arm; you might need it.

Comment: Maybe you put them inside a script block, maybe even unknowingly, but put these in a clean html and that won't happen

Comment: @devlincarnate: In a meteor app, it's "magic"; the css file in the same subdirectory is automatically used; other classes in it are being utilized just fine.

Comment: i'm suspecting it might be the way you've included/linked your css file... which is why i asked for you to show it.  i'm sure someone  on the black market would love a left arm...

Comment: Just to make things clear, you tried a bunch of versions of your css, all resulting in the errors you posted, right? And no csd at all is fine?

Comment: It helps (somewhat) to put the html inside, rather than outside,the ending "body" tag. That cleared up the error; but it's still not displaying on the page...

Comment: ok, so that rules out my theory.  can you tell if the css is being overridden by something else (looking at firebug or whatever flavor of dev tool you use) ?

Comment: @devlincarnate: It's not displaying at all, now, and the CSS class is at the very end of the .css file, so it can't be elbowed out of the way, I don't think...???

Comment: to test:  put your css inline (in the label html as a style attribute).  if that works, then the issue is with override, or perhaps you need to specify label.reditalics in the css in order to target the class.

Comment: Have you manually reloaded your browser window or just let meteor restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *font-color* attribute in css. It's just *color*.

The quotes around italic and red are also optional but not the source of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I'm using now. I've tried it both with and without encasing "red" in quotes, and either way, the label thinks it belongs in the Winchester Mystery House.

Comment: Please post the traceback from your meteor console.

Comment: All down but nine; set 'em up on the other alley, pard. IOW, I don't know how to do that; I'm doing this in Windows (7), so I'll search around. So far, I see Linux info...

Comment: It ended up being a dumb mistake on my part - it was there, but I didn't see it because it wasn't where I was looking for it/expecting it to be. In my defense, there are other red labels on the page, and so it didn't stand out all that much.

Comment: facepalms are the best ;)

Comment: I prefer Coconut palms.